# What's wrong with my SQL statement (DIFFERENCE function)

Tags: sql-server

Could someone explain me why I get different DIFFERENCE values here:

```
select RIGHT('name examplename', CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE('name examplename')))
```

this statement gives me value "examplename"

```
select DIFFERENCE('examplename', 'examplename')
```

difference here is 4 as it should

```
select DIFFERENCE('examplename', RIGHT('name examplename', CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE('name examplename'))))
```

but this statment gives me difference value 0, why?

Comment: `select DIFFERENCE('examplename', ' examplename')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this query for your problem.

```
select REPLACE (RIGHT('name examplename', CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE('name examplename'))), ' ','') 

select DIFFERENCE('examplename', 'examplename')


select DIFFERENCE('examplename', REPLACE (RIGHT('name examplename', CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE('name examplename'))), ' ',''))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a leading space on one of them.

If you look at the `SOUNDEX` values returned

```
select SOUNDEX('examplename'), 
       SOUNDEX(' examplename')
```

They are entirely different. The one with the leading space returns all zeros.

[image]

I've never found SOUNDEX or DIFFERENCE useful for anything personally.

Answer (score 1):

`RIGHT('name examplename', CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE('name examplename')))` gives you
`" examplename"` not `"examplename"`. The `SOUNDEX` values for these are completely different.

To avoid the issues you need:

```
select DIFFERENCE('examplename', CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', @your_string) = 0 THEN @your_string ELSE RIGHT(@your_string, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@your_string)) - 1) END)
```

Comment: Thank you all! Another question regarding this difference statement. If there are some strings values without space, then I get error (Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function), how to get rid of it? For example if there are only "examplename" ore "name" not "name examplename".
I think I need something like this: IF charindex value  is not null/0 then -1?

Comment: Have amended my answer @Ziil

Comment: thanks, now it much more clearer and DIFFERENCE statement works as it should

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove space character also from the string.
From the first query it gives result with the space.

Use below query they gives you same result.

```
select RIGHT('name examplename', CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE('name examplename')) - 1) 

select DIFFERENCE('examplename', 'examplename')

select DIFFERENCE('examplename', RIGHT('name examplename', CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE('name examplename')) - 1) )
```

Comment: This works fine for removeing space characters. But I get error message when I try to execute smt. like that:
select DIFFERENCE('examplename', RIGHT('name examplename', CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE('examplename')) - 1) )

I have some string values without space, then "-1" is not nessesary

Comment: Replace empty string from your own query. See query provided in answer.